# SECURITY_SET_PASSWORD using DeviceIoControl() with ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX failed

Tags: deviceiocontrol

I've tried ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX or ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT in DeviceIoControl() function with ATA command SECURITY_SET_PASSWORD but it always failed with GetLastError()=87 (invalid parameter). But ATA command IDENTIFY always succeed.

OS Environment: Windows 8.1 64bit, Visual Studio 2010, my application has Administrator privillage.

My goal is issue SECURITY ERASE UNIt like this page in the 64bit Windows 8.1: https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase

Like above web page, when I tried using 'hdparm' in the ubuntu live CD to issue secure erase has been no problem with same hardware, and same SSD.

Would you please guide me what's wrong with my code?

```
    m_h = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);  
    if ( m_h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
        return 0;

#if 1
    char buffer[512 + sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX)] = { 0 };

    ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX& PTE = *(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX *)buffer;

    PTE.Length = sizeof(PTE);
    PTE.DataTransferLength = 512;
    PTE.DataBufferOffset = sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX);
    PTE.TimeOutValue = 10;
    PTE.AtaFlags = ATA_FLAGS_DATA_OUT | ATA_FLAGS_DRDY_REQUIRED;

    IDEREGS* ir = (IDEREGS*)PTE.CurrentTaskFile;
    ir->bCommandReg = 0xF1;

    strcpy(buffer + sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX) + 2, "test");

    DWORD bytes = 0;
    if (DeviceIoControl(m_h, IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), &buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytes, 0) == 0 ) {
        DWORD er = GetLastError();
        printf("error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
#else   
    DWORD dataSize = sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT) + 512;
    ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT* pPTD = (ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT*) VirtualAlloc(NULL, dataSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    pPTD->Length = sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT); 
    pPTD->DataTransferLength = 512; 
    pPTD->DataBuffer = ((char*)pPTD) + sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT); // sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT);
    pPTD->TimeOutValue =  10;
    pPTD->AtaFlags = ATA_FLAGS_DATA_OUT | ATA_FLAGS_DRDY_REQUIRED;
    pPTD->CurrentTaskFile[1] = 0x01;
    pPTD->CurrentTaskFile[6] = 0xF1;

    strcpy( ((char*)pPTD->DataBuffer) + 2, "test");

    DWORD bytes = 0;
    if (!DeviceIoControl(m_h, IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT,  pPTD,  dataSize, pPTD, dataSize, &bytes, NULL)) {
        printf("error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
#endif  
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these ATA command blocked by OS: SECURITY SET PASSWORD, SECURITY ERASE UNIT. Because I did successfully running above program at the Windows 7 32bit and Windows 7 64bit but in Windows 8 (32bit/64bit) and Windows 10 (32bit/64bit), the same program shows invalid parameter error(error code 87).

Comment: Yes, it seems so: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/fd6516bc-aa3f-46b2-bf95-e7ace8de8fd0/security-set-password-ata-command-0xf1-under-windows-8